# Will this call be executed in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

Am I correct to assume that call to 18222E214 will be never executed?

```
sub     rsp, 28h
mov     byte ptr [rsp+27h], 0
mov     al, [rsp+27h]
test    al, 1
jz      short loc_182C60C26
call    loc_18222E214
```

This is from an obfuscated library I'm analyzing.

#### Update

Later on in flow instructions just multiple

```
mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h], 7D9EAD41h
mov     eax, [rsp+20h]
mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h], 4071AA37h
mov     eax, [rsp+20h]
nop // 
mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h], 0D6C6C2CDh
mov     eax, [rsp+20h]
// so on and so forth
```

Feels just like deadstore.

Comment: What address is this code at? This matters for the (admittedly unlikely) event that the call instruction is at `loc_182C60C26` (and so the `jz` would lead there no matter whether it jumps or falls through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be. You're loading the value 0 into the al register. `test al,1` sets the Sign, Zero, and Parity flags as though an `and` instruction had been executed. If you do an `and al,1` when al contains 0, the Zero flag is set.

In your example, the Zero flag will be set by the `test` instruction, so the short jump will be taken and the `call` instruction following the `jz` will not be executed.

### Update

Since you edited your question to say that it looks like the branch is being taken, then it's likely that there's something you didn't catch. Possibilities:

- There's some code that branches to one of the instructions that follows the `mov al, [rsp+27h]` instruction.
- Some multi-threading code moves some value into `[rsp+27h]` after you put 0 in there, but before you load `al`.
- Some other thread is calling `loc_18222E214`.
- Some other scenario that I haven't thought of.

Can't solve your problem without more information.

Comment: Caveats: Maybe this is a static code dump, and there is actually additional code elsewhere that modifies the immediate in the second instructions to some other value (self-modifying code scenario). Or maybe there is an interrupt service routine (or a second thread) which also has access to the data at location `[rsp+27h]` and modifies it to some other value (volatile data scenario). We would need more context to exclude such scenarios with certainty.

Comment: Thank you, just analyzing obfuscated library and came to this, asked to be sure.

Comment: Most likely there's a branch into this code somewhere -- probably to the `mov al, [rsp+2h]` instruction.

Comment: @RomanAvdeenko: Looks like un-optimized compiler output.  This part doesn't look obfuscated, just like `bool tmp = 0` / `if (tmp) loc_18222E214()`.  Or if it's MSVC, perhaps even `if (0) loc_18222E214();` - even in debug builds, compilers like GCC and clang will remove dead code controlled by a compile-time-constant expression that a debugger can't modify.  MSVC makes actual asm for it, although usually just using registers, not memory. https://godbolt.org/z/d6xxTa7Ms shows current versions of GCC/clang/MSVC doing something similar but not exactly this asm, so maybe it was from an obfuscator.